# What's the complexity of HDBSCAN?

Tags: clustering

I can't find any complexity information about `HDBSCAN` by google or wiki.

And how about compare to OPTICS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By googling: [HDBSCAN is order of n squared](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07321.pdf) whereas [optics is order of n times log(n)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm).